# Post file content using HttpClient and get result

Tags: c#, image, post, asp.net-web-api

I have posted a text file to action method of me web api using formdata. When I am sending text file it is working fine but when I am sending image file or video file or audio file it is not working.

Post Call:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileStream));
                        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "fileForUpload");
                        using (var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:56537/api/CreateContainer/UploadBlobs", formData))
                        {
                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var productJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

At action method:

```
 try
            {
                if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
                }

                var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                var file = provider.Contents[0];
                objAzureFunctionClass.UploadBlobsToContainer(file.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, filenametoUpload, containerNametoUpload);
                return false;
            }



public bool UploadBlobsToContainer(string fileStream, string filenametoUpload, string containerNametoUpload)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerNametoUpload);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filenametoUpload);
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(GenerateStreamFromString(fileStream));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    private Stream GenerateStreamFromString(String p)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(p);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: Where is action method signature?

Comment: it looks like it only works for text files because you are reading the file as a string with this code ReadAsStringAsync in you action method try block.  you probably want to ReadAsStreamAsync instead

Comment: I'd also set the fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType to the file type you are posting in your client code as well.